# Staging & Production Sharing the Same Database server?

Tags: vps, database, database-administration

I am currently trying to setup a staging environment for our live website. (Magento e-com site Here is our current setup:

- One droplet for Prod Web Server (Apache, PHP, etc.)
- One droplet for Prod Database Server (MySQL)
- One droplet for staging web server (created from snapshot of the prod server)

So the last thing to do would be to setup the staging database server but do I need another droplet for it?

The previous developer says I can just create a new database on the prod database server and use that for staging but wouldn't that cause unnecessary load / strain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the last thing to do would be to setup the staging database server
>   but do I need another droplet for it?

Well, that's really up to you. Best practices say that yes, indeed you should create a separate server for your staging environment. When they share resources, there's always a chance that a change in staging could possibly harm the production environment, which should be avoided if at all possible.

> The previous developer says I can just create a new database on the
>   prod database server and use that for staging but wouldn't that cause
>   unnecessary load / strain?

The developer is right - you *could* just use a separate database. It's not wise, though. Just create a separate instance for staging.

Comment: thanks, that's what my gut was telling me. I'll try to get more budget to separate it all.